# Sony Smart Wireless Headset Pro - Control Radio from API

Tags: android, mobile, sony

I am looking for an answer about two weeks.

I took a look at *Sony Add-on SDK* but I found no references. I need to develop an app for this headset which should control radio changing stations, and if possible change playing music (less important).

Anyone know how can I do that or where could I find more information?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available to change the radio station unfortunately.  When you say change playing music I assume you mean something like skipping to the next track in a playlist?  This can be done using standard Android APIs, however this functionality is already built in to the headset by default so I'm not sure what you would be trying to accomplish by doing that.

Comment: THank you for reply. What I want is skip tracks stored in headset memory card (and change radio station, if possible), but using the phone, not the headset's buttons. I didn't find any app who do that.

Comment: Is it possible install an app in the headset? Does the headset's operational system may run programs made with Sony-SDK for phones? Does the headset will execute an small app (without graphical interface and made for smartphone) who changes radio station and manage tracks?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Skipping tracks stored on the memory card is not supported.  Also the headset itself can't run apps on it's own.  It must be connected to a phone via Bluetooth.